# Proper openmp directives for nested for loop operating on 1D array

Tags: c++, for-loop, openmp, nested-loops

I need to iterate over an array and assign each element according to a calculation that requires some iteration itself. Removing all unnecessary details the program boils down to something like this.

```
float output[n];
const float input[n] = ...;

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    output[i] = 0.0f;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
        output[i] += some_calculation(i, input[j]);
    }
}
```

`some_calculation` does not alter its arguments, nor does it have an internal state so its thread safe. Looking at the loops, I understand that the outer loop is thread-safe because different iterations output to different memory locations (different `output[i]`) and the shared elements of `input` are never altered while the loop runs, but the inner loop is not thread safe because it has a race condition on `output[i]` because it is altered in all iterations.

Consequently, I'd like to spawn threads and get them working for different values of `i` but the whole iteration over `input` should be local to each thread so as not to introduce a race condition on `output[i]`. I think the following achieves this.

```
std::array<float, n> output;
const std::array<float, n> input[n];

#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    output[i] = 0.0f;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
        output[i] += some_calculation(i, input[j]);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how this handles the inner loop. Threads working on different `i`s should be able to run the loop in parallel but I don't understand if I'm allowing them to without another `#pragma omp` directive. On the other hand I don't want to accidentally allow threads to run for different values of `j` over the same `i` because that introduces a race condition. I'm also not sure if I need some extra specification on how the two arrays should be handled.

Lastly, if this code is in a function that is going to get called repeatedly, does it need the `parallel` directive or can that be called once before my main loop begins like so.

```
void iterative_step(const std::array<float, n> &input, const std::array<float, n> &output) {
    // Threads have already been spawned
    #pragma omp for
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        output[i] = 0.0f;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            output[i] += some_calculation(i, input[j]);
        }
    }

int main() {
    ...
    // spawn threads once, but not for this loop
    #pragma omp parallel
    while (...) {
        iterative_step(input, output);
    }
    ...
}
```

I looked through various other questions but they were about different problems with different race conditions and I'm confused as to how to generalize the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want the `omp parallel` in `main`.  The `omp for` you use will only create/reuse threads for the following `for (int i` loop.  For any particular value of `i`, the `j` loop will run entirely on one thread.

One other thing that would help a little is to compute your `output[i]` result into a local variable, then store that into `output[i]` once you're done with the `j` loop.

Comment: Agreeing with the answer, further, inner loop looks like reduction.  If simple enough, promote simd reduction.